# How do I add thirdparty jar to classpath on HDP sandbox?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a third party jar that I am using for mapReduce and the container that processes the mapReduce needs my jar. I've tried adding it in yarn-site.xml, YARN_USER_CLASSPATH (variable), a bunch of lib folders in hadoop directory but no luck. HortonWorks did not have much on their site about classpaths so I am trying here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup 
{YARN_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST}
so yarn will search your custom classpath first. I found this from yarn command:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.6.0/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/bin/yarn#L27